# How can I use Type Erasure with a protocol using associated type

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, type-erasure, associated-types

I am working on a project that has a network client that basically follows the below pattern.

```
protocol EndpointType {
    var baseURL: String { get }
}

enum ProfilesAPI {
    case fetchProfileForUser(id: String)
}

extension ProfilesAPI: EndpointType {
    var baseURL: String {
        return "https://foo.bar"
    }
}

protocol ClientType: class {
    associatedtype T: EndpointType
    func request(_ request: T) -> Void
}

class Client<T: EndpointType>: ClientType {
    func request(_ request: T) -> Void {
        print(request.baseURL)
    }
}

let client = Client<ProfilesAPI>()

client.request(.fetchProfileForUser(id: "123"))
```

As part of tidying up this project and writing tests I have found the it is not possible to inject a `client` when conforming to the `ClientType` protocol.

`let client: ClientType = Client<ProfilesAPI>()` produces an error:

> error: member 'request' cannot be used on value of protocol type
>   'ClientType'; use a generic constraint instead

I would like to maintain the current pattern `... = Client<ProfilesAPI>()`

Is it possible to achieve this using type erasure? I have been reading but am not sure how to make this work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to specify type of `client`

Comment: There are multiple endpoints, the original code was written to make use of generics, for example `Client<RolesAPI>()` and so on.

Comment: But what is your exact need? Exact usage

Comment: I would like to be able to setup my api calls using a simple syntax such as `client.request(.fetchProfileForUser(id: "123"))` with the enum value within `request(...)` being set using a case from an enum that conforms to `EndpointType`. That enum is set when the instance of `client` is declared.

Comment: It is very similar to how Moya works, however I did not write this app, I have only inherited the codebase so I am not 100% clear on the reasoning originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your actual question, the type eraser is straight-forward:

```
final class AnyClient<T: EndpointType>: ClientType {
    let _request: (T) -> Void
    func request(_ request: T) { _request(request) }

    init<Client: ClientType>(_ client: Client) where Client.T == T {
        _request = client.request
    }
}
```

You'll need one of these `_func/func` pairs for each requirement in the protocol. You can use it this way:

```
let client = AnyClient(Client<ProfilesAPI>())
```

And then you can create a testing harness like:

```
class RecordingClient<T: EndpointType>: ClientType {
    var requests: [T] = []
    func request(_ request: T) -> Void {
        requests.append(request)
        print("recording: \(request.baseURL)")
    }
}
```

And use that one instead:

```
let client = AnyClient(RecordingClient<ProfilesAPI>())
```

But I don't really recommend this approach if you can avoid it. Type erasers are a headache. Instead, I would look inside of `Client`, and extract the non-generic part into a `ClientEngine` protocol that doesn't require `T`. Then make *that* swappable when you construct the `Client`. Then you don't need type erasers, and you don't have to expose an extra protocol to the callers (just EndpointType).

For example, the engine part:

```
protocol ClientEngine: class {
    func request(_ request: String) -> Void
}

class StandardClientEngine: ClientEngine {
    func request(_ request: String) -> Void {
        print(request)
    }
}
```

The client that holds an engine. Notice how it uses a default parameter so that callers don't have to change anything.

```
class Client<T: EndpointType> {
    let engine: ClientEngine
    init(engine: ClientEngine = StandardClientEngine()) { self.engine = engine }

    func request(_ request: T) -> Void {
        engine.request(request.baseURL)
    }
}

let client = Client<ProfilesAPI>()
```

And again, a recording version:

```
class RecordingClientEngine: ClientEngine {
    var requests: [String] = []
    func request(_ request: String) -> Void {
        requests.append(request)
        print("recording: \(request)")
    }
}

let client = Client<ProfilesAPI>(engine: RecordingClientEngine())
```